# objectionjs column reference is ambiguous

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I try to make a query with a join relation with objection.js.

Here is the datastructure:

[image]

Here is the query:

```
Titres.query()
      .skipUndefined()
      .whereIn('typeId', typeIds)
      .whereIn('domaineId', domaineIds)
      .whereIn('statutId', statutIds)
      .joinRelation('demarches.etapes.substances')
      .where('demarches:etapes:substances.id', substances)
      .eager('[domaine, demarches.[type, etapes.substances.domaine]]')
```

This makes an error: `column reference \"domaine_id\" is ambiguous`

**How is it possible to make it work?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE statement with duplicate column names over JOIN - PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046431/where-statement-with-duplicate-column-names-over-join-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

prefix the conflicting table: `whereIn('titres.domaineId'`