# Combine all row data based on id from more than 2 tables in a database

Tags: postgresql, express, join, knex.js

table_1

```
id | user_id | morning
1  |  1      |  apple
```

table_2

```
id | user_id | afternoon
1  |  1      |  orange
```

table_3

```
id | user_id | evening
1  |  1      |  pineapple
```

These tables are just examples and I would like to join them to return the `json` object like :

```
{'user_id': 1, 'morning': 'apple', 'afternoon': 'orange', 'evening': 'pineapple'}.
```

The Query :

```
database.select('*').
         from('table_1').
         join('table_2', 'user_id', 'user_id').
         join('table_3', 'user_id', 'user_id').
then(function() {});
```

I am using `knexjs` for the node `expressjs` server and I assume this is the way to join multiple tables. I never used join before so I am not sure if this works. Unfortunately, I get this error.

> column reference 'user_id' is ambiguous

Please help me understand the error and what went wrong. Thank you

Comment: Your error because `ambiguous` and it is pretty clear.. Because you have 3 table `morning`,`afternoon`,`evening` with same `user_id` name column. To escape that use aliasing. like `morning.user_id` and your code seems cannot work in join when i see in [documentation](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-join)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE statement with duplicate column names over JOIN - PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046431/where-statement-with-duplicate-column-names-over-join-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the column reference 'user_id' is ambiguous error,

```
app.get('/get_all_data', function(req, res) {
  database.from('table_1').innerJoin('table_2', 'table_1.user_id', 'table_2.user_id').innerJoin('table_3', 'participants.athlete_id', 'table_3.athlete_id').then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Because I am using the same column name in multiple table ( which is not a good example), I need to add the table name in front of the user_id like this 'table_1.user_id'.